# parsley.js - clear error message when using CKEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, ckeditor, parsley.js

I have spent several hours trying to get this issue to work, but I am getting nowhere fast, so I am hoping some one can assist me. I have tried many attempts, searched StackOverflow and Google.

I have a form with a `textarea`. I have implemented [`parsley.js`](http://parsleyjs.org/) on to a form. The `parsley` validation is working fine, until I add in the [`CKEditor`](http://ckeditor.com/) to the `textarea`.

The issue I have is that the `parsley` error message persists (is always displayed) when I submit the form with no value in the `CKEditor`, even after I enter characters into the `CKEditor`.

**How do I clear the parsley error message when entering data into the `CKEditor`**

I think the reason is that there is no `onKeyUp` action on the `textarea`, because the `onKeyUp` action is now operating on the `CKEditor` and the `textarea` is hidden, but then not being able to remove the parsley required error message when I enter data into the `CKEditor` is killing me.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="details_form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" data-parsley-validate>
```

Here is the textarea code:

```
<p>
    <textarea rows="10" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-maxlength="5000" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required." id="id_field" cols="40" name="field" data-parsley-id="8686" dir="ltr"></textarea>
    <span class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-8686"></span>
</p>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle with your form and javascript code ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So here is the solution ;)

HTML:

```
<textarea id="ckeditor" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-required-message="This field is required" rows="6"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
CKEDITOR.config = {
  autoUpdateElement: true,
}

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(){
  $.each( CKEDITOR.instances, function(instance) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on("change", function(e) {
      for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances )
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited due to comment by mightyspaj:

CKEditor does not actually operate ontop of the textarea element. The element gets replaced by an iframe to provide the UI. This problem sounds like the textarea is not being updated properly.

I suggest that you access the textarea by JavaScript and manually trigger different events on it to see if the validation message changes due to those triggers. Parsley might have the events it listens to documented somewhere.

When you find for sure the offending event, simply bypass the automation and fire it yourself. If you need live refreshing do for example a 1second setInterval to trigger the validation.

---

Old answer:

Sounds like you want the autoUpdateElement configuration setting: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoUpdateElement

CKE does not operate directly on the textarea, it creates an iframe and does some other magic. So, the underlying element needs to be updated. You can do this manually using the `updateElement()` function or you can try `autoUpdateElement` setting above.

Comment: This is incorrect, as shown in the docs it says `Defaults to: true`. I still have the problem despite this